# Django Serializer: How can I validate a model instance?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm pretty new to Django Serializers and still confused on how they work.

I have a fairly general scenario wherein I'm calling my api which simply sets a field in my model object and saves it (assume the record is already present and it is just being updated). However, I need to validate this model object before saving it.

**api.py**

```
@detail_route(methods=['POST'], url_path='submit-draft')
def submit_draft(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    booking = self.get_object()

    # serializer with custom validations.
    serializer = self.get_serializer(booking)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    booking.submit_draft(by=request.user)
    booking.save()

    data = serializers.BookingDetailSerializer(booking, context={'request': request}).data

    return response.Ok(data)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class BookingCreateUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date = serializers.CharField()

    duration = serializers.IntegerField(required=True, )

    created_by = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault(), )

    modified_by = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault(), )
    ....

    class Meta:
    model = models.Booking
        fields = [
        'title',
        'date',
        'duration',
        'client',
        'created_by',
        'modified_by',
        ....
    ]
```

However, I get this error:

`AssertionError: Cannot call '.is_valid()' as no 'data=' keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance.`

I understand that the serializer is expecting a dictionary rather than the actual modal object. But I can't figure out how to achieve what I want to ie. validate a model object. Can anyone please suggest the right approach?

Comment: mod**a**l or mod**e**l?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django-rest-framework: Cannot call \`.is\_valid()\` as no \`data=\` keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731013/django-rest-framework-cannot-call-is-valid-as-no-data-keyword-argument)

Comment: @cezar modEl. Corrected it.

Comment: @Todor it's a different issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally worked after spending almost a day scratching my head.

**api.py**

```
@detail_route(methods=['POST'], url_path='submit-draft')
def submit_draft(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Step1. Get current model instance.
    booking = self.get_object()

    # Step2. Serialize the model instance using same serializer as in Step5.
    booking_data = serializers.BookingDetailSerializer(booking, context={'request': 
    request}).data

    # Step3. Deserialize the data from Step2 (using `BookingCreateUpdateSerializer` serializer 
    as mentioned in description and check for validations.
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=booking_data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)       

    # Step4. If no validation error, set the required field and save the instance.
    booking.submit_draft(by=request.user)
    booking.save()

    # Step5. Return response.
    data = serializers.BookingDetailSerializer(booking, context={'request': request}).data

    return response.Ok(data)
```

I learnt something more about the serializers today. We can pass around model instances into different serializers and change its shape as per our requirements.

Comment: Python uses `#` for comments, not `//`.

Comment: oops :P Java developer here who transitioned to python recently.

Answer (score 5):

You can use serializer to:

1) serialize your object to a dictionary. In this case, you dont need to call is_valid as the object has been already created and it has valid values. So you can do the following:

```
serializer = BookingCreateUpdateSerializer(booking)

return Response(serializer.data)
```

2) serialize an input and create new object using the serializer. In this case, input is a dictionary and it needs to be validated first before calling save. And you can do something like this:

```
serializer = BookingCreateUpdateSerializer(data=input_dict)
serializer.is_valid()
serializer.save()
```

**Update to answer the comment**

You can do the following to update an instance using the serializer:

```
serializer = BookingCreateUpdateSerializer(booking, data=input_data_to_update, partial=True)
serializer.is_valid()

instance = serializer.save()

# and serialize the updated instance for response using another serializer
output_data = BookingDetailSerializer(instance).data
```

Comment: `1) serialize your object to a dictionary. In this case, you dont need to call is_valid as the object has been already created and it has valid values. So you do`:

I have a situation where while creating the record first time, I have a different set of validations (using different serializer) but at the time of updating it, I am using a different serializer with different set of validations.

(Imagine a draft record and a completely filled record)
So this may not work as it still needs to be validated.

Comment: `2)  serialize an input and create new object. In this case, input is a dictionary and it needs to be validated first before calling save. So you do:`

how do i convert my modal instance `Booking` to `input_dict`?

Comment: it is the data property of the serializier which returns a ReturnDict . You just need to specify the serializer's fields to return the fields of your model which you want to get.
And you can do one  serializer for create and another one for update ( which can have different fields ).

Comment: hmm...i don't understand it. Can you please check my api method and modify it?
As you can see, I use a separate serializer while returning the data which is purely for view purposes: `BookingDetailSerializer`. And I had to use the given serializer: `BookingCreateUpdateSerializer` to validate and save the instance. So i'm not sure how it will all work in the same method.

Comment: there is no `data=input_data_to_update`. I just needed to validate the model instance and set a field (`booking.submit_draft(by=request.user)`). Anyway, thanks for all the help. I finally figured out the solution and wrote it down here.

Comment: Ok, if it works for you - fine. but the step3 in your code is redundant. you are validating data which has already been validated previously ( when the booking instance was created ).

Comment: When the booking instance was created i validated fields a,b&c using  serializer 1. Now when i’m updating it, i’m validating fields d,e&f using serialiser 2. edit: hmm...now that you’ve mentioned it i think Step5 is redundant because i’m already serialising it once in step2.

Comment: Can anybody elaborate why DRF insists on `data` and `partial` when fed with an actual model instance? That feels like the framework is fighting against you when you just want to use it in a totally natural way. I just wanted to call `headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)` when having an already valid and saved model instance and had to go to that very same trouble.