# How to serialize a list of objects?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The Django-Rest-Framework documentation (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) gives the following example for serializing a list of objects:

```
queryset = Book.objects.all()
serializer = BookSerializer(queryset, many=True)
serializer.data
```

I try to do something similar with the following code:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def postComments(request, pk):
    """
    Retrieve all comments with originalPostId = pk.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        comments = Comment.objects.all()
        comments = comments.filter(originalPostId = pk)
        serializer = CommentSerializer(comments, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.data)
        logger.error(serializer.errors)
```

However, right off the bat I get the following error: `` AssertionError: Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance. ``

This other post ([django-rest-framework: Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was passed when instantiating the serializer instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731013/django-rest-framework-cannot-call-is-valid-as-no-data-keyword-argument?rq=1)) seems to address this, but the answer suggests that putting in `data=` when calling my `CommentSerializer` would serve to deserialize instead of serialize, which is not what I want.

However, when I do run with the line `serializer = CommentSerializer(data=comments, many=True)` I get the error`{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Expected a list of items but got type "QuerySet".', code='not_a_list')]}`

Here is my serializer, in case that matters:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    poster = UserSerializer()
    community = CommunitySerializer()
    originalPost = PostSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['post', 'community', 'poster', 'originalPost', 'originalPostId']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        userData = validated_data.pop('poster')
        user = User.objects.get_or_create(username=userData['username'],
                                                       email=userData['email'],
                                                       first_name=userData['first_name'],
                                                       last_name=userData['last_name'],
                                                       password=userData['password'])[0]
        validated_data['poster'] = user
        communityData = validated_data.pop('community')
        community = Community.objects.get_or_create(name=communityData['name'])[0]
        validated_data['community'] = community

        originalPostData = validated_data.pop('originalPost')
        originalPost = Post.objects.get_or_create(id = validated_data['originalPostId'])[0]
        validated_data['originalPost'] = originalPost

        comment = Comment.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return comment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def postComments(request, pk):
    """
    Retrieve all comments with originalPostId = pk.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        comments = Comment.objects.all()
        comments = comments.filter(originalPostId = pk)
        serializer = CommentSerializer(comments, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Getting rid of the `is_valid()` check made it work. I guess I just needed to believe in myself~

Comment: very weird flex but okay

Answer (score 0):

is_valid is used for the validating user input data, so no need of call is_valid.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def postComments(request, pk):
    """
    Retrieve all comments with originalPostId = pk.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(originalPostId = pk).all()
        serializer = CommentSerializer(comments, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```